# Is this can be the simplest way of executing queries in JDBC (JAVA)

Tags: java, jdbc

In the process of learning of JDBC , I created below interface and classes for easy programming in future use . I believe still there is a possibility of doing simpler than this . What's my program does is getting results by giving Query String instead of doing all procedures like loading driver class, creating Connection and Statement objects and getting results from them. Will there be any simpler way of doing this and enhance the features in future ??

MyConnection.java  ---- Interface

```
package com.cherukuri.jdbc;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

public interface MyConnection {

public static String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
public static String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3305/STUDENTS";
public static String USER = "root";
public static String PASSWORD = “********";

default void loadDriver() {

    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Connection getConnection();

public Statement getStatement();
}
```

DataBaseConnection.java

```
package com.cherukuri.jdbc;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

public class DataBaseConnection implements MyConnection {

Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;

@Override
public Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER,
                PASSWORD);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}

@Override
public Statement getStatement() {
    connection = getConnection();
    try {
        statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return statement;
}

public ResultSet runQuery(String Query) {

    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    statement = getStatement();
    try {
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(Query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return resultSet;

}

}
```

TestBaseConnection.java

```
package com.cherukuri.jdbc;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TestDataBaseConnection {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DataBaseConnection dbcon = new DataBaseConnection();

    ResultSet rs = dbcon.runQuery("Select * from tblStudent");
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " ------------------- "
                    + rs.getString(2));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You currently aren't using the interface for anything, so you could remove that. (Move its methods and fields into `DataBaseConnection`)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for opinions/code review, which might be more on-topic on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Spring JDBC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) which simplifies JDBC access in a way similar to your wrapper classes. It removes the need for some bolierplate code and manages the database connection for you.